# MySql Query for displaying messages betweeen two users

Tags: jquery, ajax, system, message, private-messaging

I got a unique sender_id and a reciever_id i had a mysql query before like `WHERE "sender_id" AND/OR "reciever_id" LIKE "value1" AND/OR "value2"` but i cant remember it and figure it out pls need some help ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Won't simply doing this work?

```
SELECT FROM messages WHERE (sender_id=value1 AND receiver_id=value2) OR (sender_id=value2 AND receiver_id=value1)
```

Comment: stupid question how to implement a var in this query ?

Comment: what language are you using server-side?

Comment: found a solution for the var appache iam using but he didnt output me a message anyway is there another query solution ?